# Number and Capitalization of Phrase

Tags: grammatical-number, capitalization

At work we have what we call "environments" (groups of computers, essentially). Each environment has a number (e.g., Environment 1). I maintain a list of the environments. I am unsure how to capitalize and pluralize the subtitles for each environment's page. For example, some pages are for multiple environments. I am creating the page for 11 and 12, and I am unsure which of the following subtitles is correct:

1. This contains information for Environment 11 and 12.
2. This contains information for Environments 11 and 12.
3. This contains information for environment 11 and 12.
4. This contains information for environments 11 and 12.

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: If you given your dog the name "Dog", you capitalize it. If you've given your environments the name "Environments", you capitalize. The concept of environments, like dogs, is generic and doesn't need capitalization. In a subtitle, you can choose to capitalize if you'd like, but your readers will ask for consistency. Also, if this is technical documentation, consider "Environments 11 and 12"--"this contains information for" is implied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each environment is a separate thing, so listing two or more together by their numbers (or two things by their personal names, so to speak), without using the word, or the greater name, with each separately, makes that greater name plural.

Yes, capitalizing Environment is a good idea in this case, since "Environment X" is being used as a sort of place name, and Environment is also being used as a title (for a type of place).

Therefore, number 2 is the best choice.